number of possible arrangements of n coins
Had this question in a programming class and was meant to be solved using a recursive algorithm. But I was wondering if there was a combinatorics solution.
I tried counting the number of possible partitions of the N coins using $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \left\{ n \atop k \right\}$. But I do not know how to count the number of partitions with a single maximum partition.
QUESTION
In this question, we will be considering a game played with N coins. We can
arrange these coins into several different piles. A winning arrangement of coins
is a sequence of piles containing all the coins such that each pile is no larger
than the last. In other words, the pile sizes are monotonically decreasing. For
example, if I had 4 coins, the 5 winning arrangements are: {4}, {3, 1}, {2, 2},
{2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}. That is, just a pile of 4 coins, a pile of 3 followed by a
pile of 1, a pile of 2 followed by a pile of 2, and so on.

It appears you want the number of partitions of $n$, for which no simple formula is known.
